# In swift 3, when we create a dispatchWorkItem, what does DispatchWorkItemFlags parameter mean?

Tags: swift3, grand-central-dispatch

What is the useage of the parameter DispatchWorkItemsFlag when we create a dispatchWorkItem in swift 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DispatchWorkItemFlags are an option set that configure the behavior of a DispatchWorkItem value, including its quality of service class and whether to create a barrier or spawn a new detached thread.

Type Properties:

1. static let assignCurrentContext: DispatchWorkItemFlags
2. static let barrier: DispatchWorkItemFlags
3. static let detached: DispatchWorkItemFlags
4. static let enforceQoS: DispatchWorkItemFlags
5. static let inheritQoS: DispatchWorkItemFlags
6. static let noQoS: DispatchWorkItemFlags